# Authenticating Microsoft Dynamics in PHP

Tags: php, rest, soap, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I am trying to integrate Microsoft Dynamics Online with my website. However, I am struggling to find a decent way to authenticate via the API (whether it'd be REST or SOAP) using PHP. Most examples use the Microsoft CRM SDK (in .NET) to authenticate. However, my website is based in PHP and I would like to know how you gain access to the Microsoft Dynamics API (REST and/or SOAP).

Does anyone know a suitable way to authenticate with the Microsoft dynamics API via php?

Answer (score 1):

From Dynamics CRM 2016 onwards (v8.0) - we got REST API endpoint for cross platform integrations. It will look like this: `https://crmorgname.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.0/accounts`

SOAP endpoints are deprecated, REST/JSON/Odata based CRM web api endpoint is the game changer. We can use XMLHttpRequest or any means to hit that endpoint with prompt VERB like PUT, GET or POST for our purpose.

To get authenticated - we have to use OAuth, for that we need to register the PHP app in Azure Active directory & enable the permissions for Dynamics CRM online. Once done we can use that Client ID & Client secret to get authenticated and the BEARER TOKEN can be used for API calls.

Comment: Hi Arun, do you have any PHP example of this? A clients asks me to retrieve informations from his Microsoft Dynamics, he provided me with an URL, a Client ID and a Client Secret and I'm not sure how to use that, probably in a cURL request but I don't know how to pass the variables.

Comment: @rAthus see if this helps - https://www.example-code.com/phpExt/dynamics_crm_oauth2_token.asp

Answer (score 0):

The only type of authorization works for Dynamics CRM Online - using Windows Live ID. There is a good (and it's important - working) example of connecting to CRM Online from PHP in official "Dynamics CRM 2011 Developer Training Kit".

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23416

see \CRM2011KitUpdated\Labs\CRMOnlinefromPHP

At least it worked for me, my library is based on that example.

Comment: I tried this one and it failed partially for me. Since the latest version of CRM online works with Office 365, this code is outdated. I had to change https://login.live.com/liveidSTS.srf to https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf according to the following site: [link](http://mscrmtools.blogspot.be/2012/08/php-to-crm-online-easy-way-to-do.html). I am still not sure whether this is correct of not, since it breaks the first part of the authentication step in LiveIdManager.php.

Comment: But CRM online is still working with Windows Live ID, and this solution works for me right now. My LiveIdManager.php still works with "https://login.live.com/liveidSTS.srf". But I'm not able to advise anything about Office 365 method, sorry. I did not use it

Comment: The URL to microsoft.com is broken

Comment: May be this link will be helpful - http://ebanshi.cc/questions/1929618/authenticating-microsoft-dynamics-in-php